# does ValueError: 'rat' is not in list means not exist in tokenizer

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, bert, tokenization

Does this error means that the word doesn't exist in the tokenizer

```
return sent.split(" ").index(word)
ValueError: 'rat' is not in list
```

the code sequences like

```
def sentences():
   for sent in sentences:
       token = tokenizer.tokenize(sent)
       for i in token :
           idx = get_word_idx(sent,i)
def get_word_idx(sent: str, word: str):
    return sent.split(" ").index(word)
```

sentences split returns `['long', 'restaurant', 'table', 'with', 'rattan', 'rounded', 'back', 'chairs']`
which `rattan` here is the problem as i think

Comment: The first `return` statement gives the index of a specific word in the sentence. The issue is simply that the list of words in the sentence does not contain the word 'rat' .

Comment: i think that because the tokenization tokenized the words so when it got `rattan` word it got `rat` which is doesn't exist in the list already ..  should i add it as new_token ? as i tried to add `rattan` and the error is solved , does that right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a tokenizer doesn't have a dictionary of predefined words, so anyway it doesn't make sense to "add a new token" to a tokenizer.

Instead it uses indications in the text in order to separate the tokens. The most common indication is of course a whitespace character `" "`, but there are lots of cases where it's more complex than that. This is why there would be many cases where the second method with `sent.split(" ").index(word)` would not return the same tokens (punctuation marks, for example).

Also the tokenizer doesn't change the text, so if the sentence contains the word `rattan` it cannot transform it into the word `rat`. Why are you testing this? Btw [rattan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rattan) is a real word, in case this is the issue.

Comment: i tried to get embedding for the words in my file which contains sentences but got this error. excuse me can you help in this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/107238/how-can-bert-be-applied-in-image-captioning

Comment: @Begnnier ok, you seem to have a confusion between the tokenizer and the pretrained word embedding model, these two are independent. it's totally normal than some words are not present in a pretrained embedding model: it can happen with proper names, spelling errors, or even rare words like 'rattan'. In general the solution is to simply discard the words which are not in the pretrained model, instead of raising an error. I can't answer your other question, I'm not knowledgeable enough about BERT and image captioning (fyi it's a quite advanced task, it might be a bit ambitious).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and help and your time :-)